# Can't Access Netlify React Environment Variables

Tags: reactjs, deployment, environment-variables, netlify

I'm having trouble accessing environment variables in React which I set in Netlify

[image]

This is what it looks like on Netlify

[image]

And this is my code in react. This returns undefined. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to prefix the variable with `REACT_APP_` - which you did.

After you set an environment variable in netlify you need restart your dev server otherwise the changes will not be accessible in your local web app.